# Automatically data update from realtime database to firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible when firebase real-time database updates that will automatically insert the updated value to firestore collection without any app running?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firebase to automatically replicate data from Firebase Realtime Database to Firestore, but you can build it yourself with the built-in APIs of these two databases and [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). Use a Cloud Functions [Realtime Database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to detect the writes to RTDB, and then write the data to the correct collection in Firestore.